# How do i get value of concatenated hyperlink using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Ex:

```
H1= stackoverflow.com/questions/8956331/how-to-get-results

H1 = HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1)) 

$objWorkSheet->getCell( 'H1')->getValue()
```

returns

```
"HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1))"
```

instead of URL

Answer (score 0):

`getValue()` will return the raw data from the cell, in the case of a cell containing a formula, then this is the actual formula

```
$objWorkSheet->getCell( 'H1')->getCalculatedValue();
```

will return the actual evaluated result of that formula

**EDIT**

I hope that your formula

```
HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1))
```

begins with an `=` sign

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1))
```